# ClassCastException when using design support library 23.2.0 or superior

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

I'm trying to implement a [Modal BottomSheet](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html#) in my project and it requires design support library 23.2.0 or superior. Previously to this, I was using 23.0.0

The fact is that the only change in my project is from

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

and it gives me a ClassCastException saying that LinearLayout.LayoutParams cannot be cast to ActionBarOverlayLayout.LayoutParams but the trace doesn't points to any of my code lines. Here it is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams
                                                                 at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.applyInsets(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:204)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:402)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17331)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5376)
                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2548)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17331)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2279)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1393)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1592)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1251)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6540)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried library 24.x and the issue persists.

I think the problem maybe its related to my Theme and the action bar, but I tried with `NoActionBar` themes and setting `windowNoTitle` to true and `windowActionBar` to false and I got nothing.